# C++ programming ... stuck on if..else if... conditions

Tags: c++, if-statement

I created this little software which can calculate the surface and the perimeter of the rectangle and the square. However, it is getting very hard for me to run this program. What I mean is that when I try to run it, the software works fine for the "square" part, but it closes immediately when I go to the "rectangle" part. Can anyone help me? Thank you very much!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
double a, b, c, answer, x, y, z;
cout << "Square (1) or rectangle (2) ";
cin >> x ;
if (x==1)
{
    cout << "Square side:  ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << " Type (2) if you would like to calculate the Perimeter or (1) if you would like to calculate the surface?";
    cin >> y;
    if (y == 1)
    {
        cout<<"The surface of the square is: ";
        answer = ( a * a );
        cout << answer << endl;
    }
    else if (y == 2)
    { 
        cout << "The perimeter of the square is: ";
        answer = (4*a);
        cout << answer << endl;
     }     
else if (x==2)
{
     cout << "The first side of the rectangle is: ";
     cin >> c;
     cout << "The second side of the rectangle is: ";
     cin >> b;
     cout << " Type (2) if you would like to calculate the Perimeter or (1) if you would like to calculate the surface? ";
     cin >> z;
     if (z == 1)
     {
         cout << "The surface of the rectangle is: ";
         answer = (c*b);
         cout << answer<<endl;
      }
      else if (z == 2)
      { 
          cout << "The perimeter of the rectangle is: ";
          answer = 2 * (c + b);
          cout << answer << endl;
       }
   }
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Improve code-brace formatting, use the standard or java convention. Also avoid system() calls, they make your program platform-dependant.

Comment: Please fix your code and indentation. This [can't be your real code](http://ideone.com/0En4A).

Answer (score 6):

You are missing a closing brace before `else if (x==2)`

It is a good idea to make the indentation match the braces - easier to spot this type of bug 
`

Comment: For instance, pick one style in http://www.riedquat.de/prog/style and stick to it.

Comment: Yes I understood the problem of my software! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You have a curly bracket(}) missplaced. You need to close it before `else if (x==2)` because otherwise the else if applies to `else if (y==2)` instead to x == 1. Improve your code style as pointed in  IntermediateHacker's comment and you should be able to avoid such errors.

Comment: Thank you! It was very helpful. I solved the problem of the braces and everything was fine. I'll try to improve my style as I still am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I have spend a lot of time formatting your code. Still there are obvious problems with it. The curly braces just do not match. You don't even have opening brace for the main method. You also do not have curly brace before `else if (x==2)`. If you have paid some more effort formatting your code it would have been easier for you to detect your problem.

Comment: thank you very much, I figured it out. In fact I'm a beginner, I just started learning C++ only yesterday, and as I read some things about operators and if else conditions, I thought it would be a good idea to make something complex. Thanks again!!